# tiny_tds row count (affected_rows) not working

Tags: ruby, tiny-tds

Perhaps I misunderstand how to get a count of rows returned by tiny_tds, which talks to ms sql server.

The following code produces -1 rows

```
 sql = "EXEC [Arrivals] @startDate='#{@startDate}', @endDate='#{@endDate}'"
 client = TinyTds::Client.new(...)
 result = client.execute(sql)
 result.each
 p result.affected_rows   (always returns -1)
```

This code, using a loop, counts rows correctly:

```
 sql = "EXEC [Arrivals] @startDate='#{@startDate}', @endDate='#{@endDate}'"
 client = TinyTds::Client.new(...)
 result = client.execute(sql)
 @no_of_arrivals = 0
 result.each do |row|
   @no_of_arrivals = @no_of_arrivals  + 1
 end
 p @no_of_arrivals    (returns correct count)
```

I did see affected_rows in action earlier today, on a table, and it worked.  Could it have something to do with the SP... am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I'm about 2 weeks into Ruby development.  If I'm using the wrong tool to connect to MS SQL Server, I'm open to switching... but so far it's been working great, except for this minor problem.